# Issue with large file in AudioContext CreateBuffer()

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

i want to create an audio buffer with 1 channel,1190256000 length and 48000 sample rate.but i am getting an error in createBuffer() methode.please find the fiddle containing the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a length of 1,190,256,000 you are more than likely running into the buffer size limit of the browser.  If you look at the `name` property you will see the opperation you are attempting causes a NotSupportedError (in chrome, may be different in another browser).

> NotSupportedError
>
> One or more of the options are negative or otherwise has an invalid value (such as numberOfChannels being higher than supported,
>   or a sampleRate outside the nominal range).

As if you try a lower value you get a success

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
var buffer;

try {
    audioContext.createBuffer(1, 1190256000, 48000);
} catch(e){
    console.log(e.name,e.message);
}

try {
  buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 119025600, 48000);
  console.log("success",buffer);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.name,e.message);
}
```

Comment: thanks.But is there any way to create an audio buffer with this length?

Comment: Not with Chrome.  That requires over 4GB of memory.

Comment: @RaymondToy, By buffer limit I meant the limit before Chrome will run out of heap memory. The channel data of a buffer is a Float32Array typed array, and can only be so large before causing a RangeError or OutofMemoryError. For instance on my system my Chrome's heap limit is around 2.3GB (can be seen by doing `console.memory`).  That limits me to about 536,870,912 array length or 2.14GB in actual data. This is why a user will get a NotSupportedError when trying to create a buffer, like OP's attempt, as the size they used would go over the heap limit.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I was just answering @user2922212's question about being able to create that buffer.

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks for the details.